# Is there anything like unsleeping bag

Tags: phrases

"Once as a kid he'd gone out behind the house, into the wilds of pecan trees and hedges and, following a night zipped into an army-surplus **unsleeping bag**, had attempted to fry bacon over a Sterno can, managing only to cook his thumb."

Is there anything like unsleeping bag or is it just a sarcastic phrase?

Comment: Please always summarize the results of whatever research you did before asking. Doing research before posting is basic site etiquette.

Answer (score 6):

This is what is known as wry humor. It is used derisively, usually as a commentary on the miserable nature of a thing or a situation. The author is making a comment about the uncomfortable nature of the sleeping bag, which prevented the very thing it was designed to promote.

Given [more context](http://books.google.com/books?id=EHcnKJtSyAQC&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=%22following%20a%20night%20zipped%20into%20an%20army-surplus%20unsleeping%20bag%22&source=bl&ots=TN1Oaro_sL&sig=1K1KnhRa1RceeCDmt7PK0tm4qaA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Nrw_T5veIMnLrQfS84TeBw&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22following%20a%20night%20zipped%20into%20an%20army-surplus%20unsleeping%20bag%22&f=false), the sardonic humor is even more evident:

[image]

The drink tasted like Sterno, the thumb got fried instead of the bacon, etc.

*[Excerpt from a Google Books search that yielded the passage from *Drive* by James Sallis]*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any such thing. I think the author is just trying to make a derogatory implication about the quality of army-surplus sleeping bags.

Answer (score 0):

Its sarcastic I think. Haven't heard of unsleeping bags. Maybe helpful if there was one.